# What are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}^\ast \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}^\ast$? I think I count $5$ of them.

Tags: finite-groups, group-theory

What are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}^\ast \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}^\ast$? I think I count $5$ of them I think? Thank you for anyone that puts the time in to help!

Comment: You forgot a few. How many of each order did you find?

Comment: Lets see the subgroup of order $1$ is the identity, and the subgroup of order $20$ is the whole group. Then there is subgroups of order 2, 4, 5, and 10 right? Hmmm then if that is the case it appears that there is more then 5.

Comment: Hold on, ${\mathbb Z}_5^* \times {\mathbb Z}_4^*$ has only 8 elements, so something is wrong. Are you thinking of ${\mathbb Z}_5 \times {\mathbb Z}_4$ maybe? Also has more than 5 subgroups, though.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks. I still mean $\mathbb{Z}_{4}^\ast \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}^\ast$. My bad. I would still like to list the subgroups so the identity and whole group itself still work.

Comment: Ok. There are 3 subgroups of order 4, 3 subgroups of order 2; making a total of 8, including the whole group and the trivial group.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Since $\mathbb{Z}_{4}^\ast \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}^\ast$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^\ast$ which is isomorphic to $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{20}}$, would there still be $8$ subgroups of the group $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: I feel I'm missing some context here. What is $L$? Of course, ${\mathbb Z}_{20}^*$ has 8 subgroups as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ian posted nicely $$\mathbb Z_5^*\times\mathbb Z_4^*\cong\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2$$ Now think about the latter group. If $H\leq \mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2=G$ then $|H|=1,~2,~4,~\text{or}~~8$ according to [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) and this fact that $|\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2|=8$. Since we are working with easy groups so we can list all elements of $G$ as follows:

$$(0_{\mathbb Z_4},0_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~(1_{\mathbb Z_4},0_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~(2_{\mathbb Z_4},0_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~(3_{\mathbb Z_4},0_{\mathbb Z_2})\\
(0_{\mathbb Z_4},1_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~ (1_{\mathbb Z_4},1_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~(2_{\mathbb Z_4},1_{\mathbb Z_2}),~~(3_{\mathbb Z_4},1_{\mathbb Z_2})$$ Clearly some subgroups of $G$ is the cyclic ones, but we should care about this point that some of them may be generated twice. For example: $$H_1=\langle(0,0)\rangle=\langle0_G\rangle\\H_2=\langle(1,0)\rangle=\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(0,0)\}\cong\mathbb Z_4\\ H_3=\langle(2,0)\rangle=\{(2,0),(0,0)\}\cong\mathbb Z_2\\ H_4=\langle(3,0)\rangle=\{(3,0),(2,0),(1,0),(0,0)\}\cong\mathbb Z_4\\ H_5=\langle(0,1)\rangle=\{(0,1),(0,0)\}\cong\mathbb Z_2 $$  Using GAP (in particular, `AllSubgroups` and `StructureDescription`), possible isomorphism types of subgroups of $G$ are:

```
1, C2, C2 x C2, C4, C4 x C2
```

Comment: Nice work! +1 for groups!

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times\cong\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^\times\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.